# Sum of string lengths within a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that is: `[ ["Hello", "dad"], ["I"], ["am", "driving", "away"] ]` and I need to add the length of each string within the list and add it in a new list, each index of the new list would be the sum of the lengths of each list, so essentially, the new list would be `[8, 1, 13]`.

Currently my code is:

```
new_list = []
 
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
      
      new_list.append(len(x[i][j]))
```

When I run the code with `[ ["Hello", "dad"], ["I"], ["am", "driving", "away"] ]`, it gives me
`[5, 3, 1, 2, 7, 4]` instead of `[8, 1, 13]`. I am currently having difficulty with totaling up the lengths of each string in each list.

Comment: `[sum(map(len, v)) for v in x]`

Comment: `[sum(len(s) for s in sublist) for sublist in data]`

Answer (score 0):

```
[len("".join(i)) for i in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, that you're adding the length of each sub-list's string instead of summing per sub-list.

#### Quick fix

Here's the fix (wrong statement out-commented):

```py
new_list = [] # would rename to sum_list
for i in range(len(x)):
    length_sum = 0 # reset for each sub-list
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
        # new_list.append(len(x[i][j]))
        length_sum += len(x[i][j]) # sum the length of each sub-list element
    new_list.append(length_sum)
```

#### Improving the code

You could also use a for-each loop like:

- `for sub_list in x` to iterate through the top-list's elements (here sub-lists)
- `for element in sub_list` to iterate through the sub-list's elements (here strings)
- then assessing the length with `len(element)`

This might improve readability and can be done like currently with loop-blocks (introduced by `:`).

The other answers proposed a more *pythonic* implementation using **list-comprehension**.

Comment: Typo in `lenght_sum`.